# Crashlytics with Ionic 3 app

Tags: firebase, ionic3, crashlytics

I have implemented [**Firebase**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) plugin with ionic 3 app. It is working fine. Could you tell me how can I use [**Crashlytics**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) with this plugin? According to the doc it seems for the native apps. So how can we do it with Ionic 3?

There is a plugin [**cordova-fabric-plugin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-fabric-plugin?activeTab=readme) which we can use with ionic apps. But it seems we don't need it anymore since this note on the native apps doc: Any guidance please?

> Note: If you're upgrading from Fabric Crashlytics, remove the Fabric
>   API key from your AndroidManifest.xml. Delete the key's meta-data tag,
>   which should have io.fabric.ApiKey and the API key.

Comment: where did you see that comment? I was using crashlytics in ionic 3 last year (just not right now).

Answer (score 3):

In theory you should setup the FabricPlugin just as described. (the versions required of the firebase are lower than the once included)

To setup on ionic I recommend to read the following issue: https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin/issues/70

Short Version: Create then a custom error handler

```js
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: FabricErrorHandler},
```

and then your custom Error Handler

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as stacktrace from 'stacktrace-js';

@Injectable()
export class FabricErrorHandler extends IonicErrorHandler {
    constructor (public analytics: Analytics) {
        super();
    }

    handleError(error) {
        window.fabric.Crashlytics.addLog('crash triggered');
        stacktrace.get().then(
            trace => window.fabric.Crashlytics.endNonFatalCrash(error.message, trace)
        );

        super.handleError(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are using `fabric.Crashlytics`. But now it is firebase product. You can see `Note: If you're upgrading from Fabric Crashlytics, remove the Fabric API key from your AndroidManifest.xml. Delete the key's meta-data tag, which should have io.fabric.ApiKey and the API key.` on this doc (under 3rd note): https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Comment: Hope now we can't do that with `firebase crashlytics` according to the above doc. It seems now it supports only with a native. Your thoughts?

Comment: I would assume that this just mentions the native code (and where you store the api key) - after that the interface itself for the native app did not change. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link
https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/features

Crashlytics with Ionic 3 app

First off, follow what they say… installing the IDE plugin, etc.
Now. Ionic uses gradle for its building. You would expect the install to work right away, but it wont. Ionic/Cordova overwrites the build.gradle definitions in the dependencies section.

Anyway, first off open build.gradle, and in buildscript > repositories, if its not already in there, add

jcenter() maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

Next, there are 3 dependencies for each gradle version. if you know what version you are running, great. otherwise add the following to all of them.
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

Now what we need to do is extend gradle’s build.
Create a file in your android/ios directory called build-extras.gradle.
Inside this, we need to define the repositories.

apply plugin: 'io.fabric' repositories { jcenter() maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } } dependencies { // Crashlytics Kit compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') { transitive = true } }

Now, when you run or build the app, it should work, although Fabric.io 79 won’t recognize your app.
We will need to install a cordova plugin,
The one I use is:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-fabric-plugin 946

After this is installed, add a force crash and rebuild & run your app.

If it is still not working, make sure you do not have any ad-blocking software installed. Even if you don’t but you have in the past, reinstall it and make sure all settings are reset (I.E AdAway edits your hosts files, uninstalling it does not reset them, you need to reset them then you can uninstall them).

Hope this has helped anyone else who had issues setting it up.

EDIT
Currently Crashlytics does not support custom stacktraces. All crashes will come from the Crashlytics/Fabric.io plugin. You have to use the logs to specify the error.

Answer (score -2):

Fabric does not support any non-native platforms except for Unity at this time. However, as @wodka mentioned, there are community workarounds.